# How to check if the chosen path comes from USB or network drive?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

Is it possible in UWP (and WinRT) to check if file/folder selected via open dialog comes from removable disk or network location?

Answer (score 0):

[Get Drive Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx) will tell you if it's a network drive or not. Unfortunately the API listed in that page for detecting USB isn't available to UWP.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to call Win32 API directly:

```
    [DllImport("api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll")]
    private static extern DriveType GetDriveType([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpRootPathName);
```